# Mitigation Plan for revenue outflows arising from unresolved implementation issues in change management gaps

Tags: risk-management, change-management

Good day!
Looking for recommendations / mitigation plans for revenue outflows arising from unresolved implementation issues and change management gaps?

Comment: Please add some specifics/details to help  us give you meaningful recommendations.

Comment: user614, I would recommend you formally accept answers to your questions. That will help encourage the community to participate in your questions.

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi user614, since this is extremely broad, we were thinking you could [edit] the post a bit to narrow the scope. Perhaps you could describe the problem you're hoping this would solve?  Even though this is closed, you can still edit it, and we can look at possibly reopening. If you need any help with edits, please ask in our [chat] or in [meta]. We're happy to help, Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is helpful to allocate a sum of money and time to addressing risks when planning and budgeting your project. This is **NOT** a budget for general use to address cost overruns. Instead, specific amounts should be allocated to specific risks, and this "risk budget" should only be tapped into if and when specific risks are realized, and with appropriate approval/justification documented using your project change control procedures.

If you have experience with particular implementation issues or change management gaps on previous projects you should have some idea of how much money to allocate for those risks. If you don't have this kind of data you may just have to make an educated guess.